# Android open mailbox show suggested contacts

Tags: android, android-intent

On Android, Im implementing a button in order to open a mailbox. When a click on this button, a pop-in appear with installed mailbox but I see suggested contact.

Someone knows how to remove this contacts ? I want to see only mailbox.

Screenshot :

[image]

My intent configuration code :

```
    // basic information
    String body = "hello"
    String recipientsList[] = { "hello@hello.com"};
    String subject = "subject"

    // configure intent to open maibox
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    // configure new email
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientsList);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

Thanks !

**EDIT - RESOLVED** : Just using code below to launch mailbox solve the problem (but modify appearance of selector)

```
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 String subject = "Feedback";
            String bodyText = "Enter text email";
            String mailto = "mailto:bob@example.org" +
                    "?cc=" + "" +
                    "&subject=" + Uri.encode(subject) +
                    "&body=" + Uri.encode(bodyText);

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailto));

            try {
                startActivity(emailIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //TODO: Handle case where no email app is available
            }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.. Maybe due to the android version ? Im on Android 7.0

Comment: @John' i also use android 7.0

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. To launch the mailbox, I used : 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "text")). With your solution, I have no problem.

But I don't know why using Intent.createChoose() display contacts..

Thank you !